# sprintf is changing the value of a boolean

Tags: c

I have the following code and after the `sprintf` function is executed, the boolean `use_custom_value` is set to false and I can't figure out why.  Here is the code with some comments:

```
bool use_custom_value;

use_custom_value = strncmp(custom_value_id, "", SZ_ID + 1);

/* use_custom_value is true */

int init_complete = localInitTable ( );

char *buf;

int  close_fp = 0;

buf = ( char * ) malloc ( 1024 * 1024 );

memset ( buf, ' ', 1024 * 1024 );

*buf = '\0';

int  filled_byte = 0;

TEST_DEF test_def;

MYSQL_RES *Result = NULL;

char where_for_test_records[100];

int  err1;

char *testp;

testp = ( char * ) malloc ( sizeof ( testp_DEF ) + 1 );

if ( use_custom_value )
{
        /* use_custom_value is true */

        sprintf ( where_for_test_records, 
                  "test='%s'", test_no );

        /* use_custom_value is false, why?*/

        Result = Query2Result ( &TestG, where_for_test_records );
}
```

Comment: What is `test_no` where is it declared and initialized?

Comment: What is `test_no`?  Presumably garbage.  Your sprintf most likely writes well past 99 characters off from `where_for_test_records`.  Look up "Undefined behavior".  `strncmp` returns an `int`.

Comment: And `TestG`. And `Query2Result`.

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps - Hi, can you explain what you mean by `sprintf most likely writes well past 99 characters off from where_for_test_records`.  Are you saying that if the string is larger than 100, it could be overwriting the memory where `use_custom_value` is allocated?  Sorry, I am fairly new to using c.

Comment: If you answer the previous comments, you will get a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Devolus - What is SSCCE?

Comment: @EugeneSh.- I'm working on it.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps - Turned out to be the length of `where_for_test_records`.  If you create an answer from that, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `test_no`?  Is it a number?  If so, you have the wrong format specifier (try `%d` instead of `%s`).

If `test_no` is indeed a string, its contents are presumably garbage. It causes your sprintf call to write well past 99 characters off from `where_for_test_records` (*test = 'test_no is more than 100 characters long'*).

Look up "Undefined behavior" on how an unrelated piece of code that does wrong affects a program in ways you do not expect.

Note that `strncmp` returns an int, not a true/false.  In fact, a return of 0 is not false at all in the context of `strcmp`!